# How to Update the models at run-time using EF core 2.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on `web API project` with `Entity framework 2.2` as `DB first approach`. My requirement is when we add a new table to the database, models should update at runtime. I know how to do this using Package Manager Console but I need to do it programmatically. How do I achieve this?

I have tried using `db.Database.Migrate();` in `startup class`.

**How should I get confirmation that models are updated?**

Comment: You want to add new classes to your project at runtime? How would that work?

Comment: @JLe Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: No. You can update the database at runtime, but not the other way around. It wouldn’t make sense either, as you would need to write some code anyway to use the models.

Comment: Imagine it is possible, then what ?

Comment: After change your database, you would have to run `Scaffold-Database` again, or otherwise create new entity class(es) to represent the new table(s). Those classes then must be compiled into the assembly that you're running. That cannot be achieved without doing a new publish. In short, it's impossible to do this during "runtime", as it's a compile-time activity.

Answer (score -1):

you need to write a method that can execute powershell command with c# and call this method in startup function

```
public class PowerShellHelper
{
    public void Execute(string command)
    {
        using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            var results = ps.AddScript(command).Invoke();
            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                Debug.Write(result.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to update model from database :

```
Scaffold-DbContext [-Connection] [-Provider] [-OutputDir] [-Context] [-Schemas>] [-Tables>] 
                    [-DataAnnotations] [-Force] [-Project] [-StartupProject] [<CommonParameters>]
```

use --force attribute to force updating model.
I'm not sure that this solution will work with you

Comment: No cigar. This won't work because the generate classes would not actually be part of the compiled assembly.